# Find a child node with particular attribute, for any number of child nodes?

Tags: .net, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

How to query XML document using Linq to XML to find a child node with particular attribute, for any number of child nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You might like to consider using **XPath**..

```
XmlNodeList list = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//nodeType[@attrName=attrValue]");

//This selects all elements of type 'nodeType' occuring anywhere in the document 
//having 'attrName' attribute of value 'attrValue'
```